# How to deploy Firebase functions and other services in multiple locations?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, deployment, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to deploy Firebase services in multiple locations?

Reading up on [Select locations for your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations) it seems like it's not possible to deploy Firebase globally.

The current multi-region locations are eur3 and nam5 which cover Europe and the US in multiple locations.

What if there is a need to cover Europe and US simultaneously? Did anyone come across the same issue, if so, I would appreciate if you'd share your experience.

EDIT:

We are using Functions and Firestore services. If we deploy functions globally we will also have to have Firestore in two projects or use the default GCP resource location for Firestore with functions in multiple regions.

Comment: Have you checked [Deploy Firebase Cloud Functions across multiple regions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52244179/13130697)?

Comment: Thank you @Dharmaraj, I edited the question to provide more information. The issue is in Firestore and the default GCP resource location. Even if I deploy functions in multiple regions, I still have my Firestore in a single location.