# How to structure a multi-region firebase app?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Currently, I have this structure:

```
- A couple of functions in a single region
- A firestore database in a single region
```

A while ago, the whole region went down, which caused issues to the users.

I want to change the structure to be in multiple regions, both the database and the functions.

How is that done in the firebase world?

Keeping in mind that when I deploy the functions in multiple regions, there should be some way to route requests to the function in the region close to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Once the database is created, the region can’t be changed. You'll have to create a new project with the new region.

By default, functions run in the us-central1 region.If you have a function that is currently in the default functions region of us-central1, and you want to migrate it to asia-northeast1, you need to first modify your source code to rename the function and revise the region. You can refer to this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region)

```
// before
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.webhook = functions
    .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
            res.send("Hello");
    });

// after
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.webhookAsia = functions
    .region('asia-northeast1')
    .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
            res.send("Hello");
    });
```

Then deploy by running:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:newfunction
```

After renaming the function with the new region, now there are two identical functions running in us-central1 and asia-northeast1.

You can also check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926048/move-firebase-project-to-another-region) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244179/deploy-firebase-cloud-functions-across-multiple-regions) which might help

Comment: After deploying a function in multiple regions, who will decide which region a request would hit? since they all are going to have the same name. I don't understand this part yet.

Comment: first set your function to the destination region, or closest to where most expected customers are located, and then alter your original function to redirect its HTTP request to the new function .check this [Best practices for changing region](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#best_practices_for_changing_region)

Comment: But what if a region goes down like last time? There should be a way that automates region selection of function when it gets called. Also, the redirection applies to http functions only. In my case most of the functions are callable. What do you think about this?

Comment: If one region goes down it will not available but other regions will continue to be available.Deploying to multiple regions, requests will be automatically routed to the closest available region, based on the location of the client making the request. This applies to both HTTP functions and callable functions.